# Return character string associated with highest value, minimum value

Tags: r

I'm struggling to even pose the question. I want to return a character strings based on their associated value within a group. So, let's say I have the following table:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Group  Name   Value 
#   <chr>  <chr>  <num>
#    VA    John     2
#    VA    James    6
#    VA    Joe      3
#    NY    Emily    6
#    NY    Dave     3
#    NY    Deb      4
```

I want to return:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#   Group   Max   Min    Med   Total
#   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <num>
#    VA    James  John   Joe   11
#    NY    Emily  Dave   Deb   12
```

Comment: Should Total = 13 (not 12) for group NY, assuming it's the sum of Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(Max = Name[Value == max(Value)], 
            Min = Name[Value == min(Value)], 
            Med = Name[Value == median(Value)], 
            Total = sum(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  Group Max   Min   Med   Total
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 NY    Emily Dave  Deb      13
2 VA    James John  Joe      11
```

Input data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("VA", "VA", "VA", "NY", "NY", "NY"), 
    Name = c("John", "James", "Joe", "Emily", "Dave", "Deb"), 
    Value = c(2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: The median calculation will not always work. E.g. `median(c(1,2,3,4))` is `2.5` and no value will match. Even worse, _dplyr_ just will silently drop the whole group in that scenario.

Comment: @thelatemail Indeed! I was just going by the example data, but thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `by` approach just base R.

```
by(dat, dat$Group, \(x) {
  with(x[order(x$Value)[c(3, 1, 2)], ], 
       data.frame(Group=el(Group), t(setNames(Name, c('Max', 'Min', 'Med'))), Total=sum(Value)))
}) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#    Group   Max  Min Med Total
# NY    NY Emily Dave Deb    13
# VA    VA James John Joe    11
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Group = c("VA", "VA", "VA", "NY", "NY", "NY"), 
    Name = c("John", "James", "Joe", "Emily", "Dave", "Deb"), 
    Value = c(2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

data.table solution (usually helpful when speed is important)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , .(Max = Name[Value == max(Value)], 
        Min = Name[Value == min(Value)], 
        Med = Name[Value == median(Value)], 
        Total = sum(Value)), by = Group]
```

Explanation:

The parameter after the first `,` is a list (data.table shorthand `.`) refering to how we want to select columns. Here we are creating 4 new transformed columns based on applying simple functions to the Name or Value columns. The "by" parameter in the data.table applies to each group (named Group), and conveniently combines it together again

Output

```
   Group   Max  Min Med Total
1:    VA James John Joe    11
2:    NY Emily Dave Deb    13
```